# What would I do if I wanted to query all tables in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Right now I'm only able to grab only a specific table from the database. I had a few theories and I tried `SELECT * FROM *` but that doesn't work at all. I would love any help given!  Here is my code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","***","photos");
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "<p>Found ".$queryResult." quote(s)</p>";

        if ($queryResult > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<a href='uploads/".$row['image']."' data-fancybox='quote'>";
                echo "<img id='img_div' src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
                echo "</a>";
            }

        } else{
            echo "There are no quotes matching your search.";
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Why you need to query from all tables??

Comment: "show tables" will give you a list of tables to loop through

Comment: Have you tried JOINS?

Comment: How would I do JOINS?

Comment: Have a read of https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php